# How to remove flagged identical lines in text files

Tags: command-line

I want to  remove selected identical lines jumbled in text file B. The identical lines are flagged with % mark in begining of line in file A. How to achive this through commandline.

eg:

`file A contents
AAA - 789
BBB - 456
% CCC - 980`

`file B contents
AAA - 789
CCC - 980
BBB - 456`

want to remove CCC - 980 in file B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the commands in a terminal,

```bsh
sed -n '/^%/p' fileA.txt | awk '{print substr($0,3)}' > tmp.txt
grep fileB.txt -vf tmp.txt > modified_file.txt
rm tmp.txt
```

The file `modified_file.txt` contains your desired results. you can use these commands in a shell script also.

### How it works:

- `sed -n '/^%/p' fileA.txt` output is, `% CCC - 980`
- `sed -n '/^%/p' fileA.txt | awk '{print substr($0,3)}'` produces `CCC - 980`, which you want to remove. I have stored it in `tmp.txt` using redirection so that **it can work with multiple lines.**
- `grep fileB.txt -vf tmp.txt` gives you the part of fileB that does not contained in `tmp.txt`. Finally stored it in `modified_file.txt`

**Alternate smart method suggested by [AvinashRaj](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497475/how-to-remove-flagged-identical-lines-in-text-files/497488#comment666375_497488):**

```
awk -v var=$(awk '$1=="%"{print $2}' fileA.txt) '$1==var{next;}1' fileB.txt
```

Comment: How about this my friend? `awk -v var=$(awk '$1=="%"{print $2}' r) '$1==var{next;}1' f` where `r` is the filename which contains the line starting with `%`, and `f` is the file you actually want to remove the duplicate lines..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have added your suggestion. But I think it will face difficulty in case of more than one `%` present in the file.

Comment: @souravc no, for that i clearly mentioned that do the operation only if the column1 contains `%`